# Displaying response from flow connected to power app / variable error

Tags: json, response, azure-logic-apps, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm succesfully posting data from a canvas app to a power automate flow which is then posting that data to an azure logic app. I'm getting back a response which is stored in the power automate flow and trying to display that response in a results page in the canvas app. This is where the problem lies, I can't get the response to be displayed in the canvass app.

I've tried adding a respond to a power app or flow action in power automate and then Setting a variable before I call the flow like the following:
Set(varEmissionValue,'Copyof-Button->manual-invoke'.Run(Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value,Dropdown2.SelectedText.Value,Dropdown3.SelectedText.Value,Dropdown4.SelectedText.Value,TextInput2.Text,TextInput3.Text,Checkbox1.Value,Checkbox2.Value).emission)

.emission is where I'm getting a failure but when searchimg online and asking chatgpt they displayed similiar things and got no error.
Then in a text label to display the response I've put in the formula for text the variable varEmissionValue then I should be able to put . the outputs I've specified in the respond to a power app or flow value.
I'll attach images because I'm terrible at explaining stuff.
[This is the image of an example I saw online] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIV6n.png)
[This is the output I want to add to my canvas app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sxRC.png)
[This is where I set my variable and posted to the power automate flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp4OL.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the data type returned to the app? What is the error message you get? Have you refreshed the reference to the flow in your app after defining the 'emission' output property?

Comment: @moshood Edit the Qs with more details so that the community can check.